# Replication "on commit"

Tags: mysql

I'll put you in context before asking my question:
I have two servers, Dev and Prod. What I would like to do is have a replication between the 2 DBs (MySQL 5.5). But I don't want the 2 DBs to always be in sync. All the modifications (data and files) will be done on the Dev server, so I would like the Dev's DB replicated on the live one only when I "commit" the changes made on the Dev server. What I want is to have a kind of versioning between my 2 DBs with ideally no down time (obviously).

Is this something possible?

Would it be a better idea to setup a SVN server for that?

I have already searched on the internet, but I didn't come across someone doing this.

Thank you!

Comment: replication is for LIVE and continuous synchronization of two or more mysql servers. If you want deferred updates, then you can't use mysql's built-in synchronization. You'll have to roll your own system.

Comment: Seems you are more interested in the concept of database schema migrations.  There are a number of libraries/tools available for doing this across various programming languages. For more information start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Replication" is not what you're looking for.  By definition really, that would replicate all changes in as fast a way as possible.  An easy way to do what you want would be to write a shell script that's only a few lines that uses [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) (to transfer between servers) and [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) (the command line utility) with the proper command line switches.  If they are on the same machine, but in different databases, you can also just use a SELECT statement to copy the applicable rows.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at this option. My DBs are not on the same machine, not even on the same network so I will not use a SELECT statement between the two, but you gave me some ideas on what I will do to achieve my goal.